# Problem converting tbl_cube with list measure into a tibble

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to convert a `tbl_cube` with a list-valued measure into a tibble, but am running into problems.

For example

```
Y <- array(1:4, dim = c(2,2))
```

is a "cube" of integers (it only has two axes so it's really a matrix) which can be turned into a `tbl_cube` as follows

```
Y_cube <- tbl_cube(dimensions = list(A = c('foo','bar'), 
                                     B = c('x','y')), 
                   measures = list(y = Y))
```

which in turn can be converted into a tibble as follows `as_tibble(Y_cube)`.

However, if we start with a list-valued array then we can create the `tbl_cube`:

```
X <- array(lapply(1:4, seq_len), dim = c(2,2))
X_cube <- tbl_cube(dimensions = list(A = c('foo','bar'), 
                                     B = c('x','y')), 
                   measures = list(x = X))
```

but `as_tibble(X_cube)` generates an error:

```
Error: Can't subset elements that don't exist.
x The locations 3 and 4 don't exist.
i There are only 2 elements.
```

I'm using `dplyr` version `dplyr_0.8.5`.

Comment: I find `tbl_cube` from an older version of `dplyr`.  Is it deprecated ?

Comment: As far as I can tell `tbl_cube` is not deprecated. See https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/tbl_cube.html (0.8.3 when I checked) and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/dplyr.pdf (0.8.5). It is marked as experimental, though.

Comment: thanks, i am using devel version and couldn't find the function

Comment: You are right: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4429 and https://github.com/hadley/cubelyr. Really I should update to the new packages and see what happens.

Comment: A very similar error still happens with current versions of the tidyverse. However, I noticed that (at least now) `as_tibble(X_cube)` succeeds, but printing it fails.